# How to ignore mistakenly committed files

Tags: android, git, controls, version

I have an android project, and mistakenly added **bin** folder to stage and committed it. Now how can I ignore this **bin** folder and ignore it for ever?
I added **bin/** to the **.gitignore** file, but nothing changes and I see all files in this folder in working copy in SourceTree.

I am using SourceTree as the git client.

Comment: Can't you commit a deletion of this folder and then add it to your .gitignore file ?

Comment: You could try: git rm bin,  then add to your gitignore:  *./bin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Along with ignoring the folder, you need to `git rm` it.  Git only ignores files that aren't already under its control.

Be aware, though:  doing so will cause git to remove that folder for anyone else who pulls those changes.  You'd better be sure that folder is just the output from building, or can otherwise be easily reconstructed.

**If you haven't published the changes yet** (that is, if you've never pushed them to anywhere and no one's pulled them from you), then you have the option of rewriting the history.  You can simply say `git reset --soft the_commit_before_you_added_bin`  (of course, you'll need the actual commit ID, or another name for it, like `HEAD~3` etc) to basically "uncommit" to right before you added it.  Your working copy will still have the latest versions of the files, but Git will all but forget you committed them.  (This also means you lose intermediate changes.)  You can then redo your commit(s), being careful to avoid `bin` this time.

Git has a `filter-branch` command that can allegedly help with automating all that, and can even preserve intermediate changes.  I've never used it, though, and couldn't tell you how to use it.

---

Obligatory Big Bold Warning:

### **Don't rewrite history that has already been published.**

Only undo/rewrite commits that have never been pushed or pulled.  Otherwise, wackiness ensues.

Comment: "git rm some_folder" removes all history of some_folder?

Comment: No.  It removes the folder, and the history will show that it did so.  That's why when someone pulls that change, their folder will disappear.  If you want to disavow all knowledge of the folder, that's a much bigger deal; everyone who's cloned the repo will have to agree to do so, and will have to remove the folder in a certain way.

Comment: Although...if no one's seen the changes yet...  (Updated.)